# How to display iframe with parameters only through javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I came across this resource where the .js file pulls out the iframe.
[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159620/how-to-display-iframe-by-a-javascript-snippet)

The js file:

```
window.document.write("<iframe src=\"somedomain.com/page.htm\"/>");
```

However i'm not sure how to add attributes such as width/height/scrolling. Further more i would also like to add an image and link it as well, at the end of the iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this *started* with document.write, just continue it:

```
document.write("<iframe src=\"somedomain.com/page.htm\"/ width=200 scrolling='no'>");
```

Note that HTML doesn't actually require quotes for attributes in certain cases (see `width`), but they could be added just as with `src`. Also `'` can be used in place of `"` and it simplifies the escaping (see `scrolling`). *Please be consistent, the above notes are just informational.*

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same method:

```
window.document.write("<iframe src=\"somedomain.com/page.htm\" width='300' height='900' ></iframe>");
```

**Note** that iframe is not a self closing element tag, however most browser will render correctly. Inside the tag you can enter so alternative content incase the browser doesn't support iframes

Answer (score 1):

can you get the reference to the Frame somehow such as this..  if its the first iframe on the page then you would use index [0]

function removeScroll()
{
window.parent.frames[0].scrolling="no";
}

Answer (score 1):

try using createElement, the native method

```
      var tempIFrame=document.createElement('iframe');
      tempIFrame.setAttribute('id','RSIFrame');
      tempIFrame.style.border='0px';
      tempIFrame.style.width='0px';
      tempIFrame.style.height='0px';
      IFrameObj = document.body.appendChild(tempIFrame);

      if (document.frames) {
        // this is for IE5 Mac, because it will only
        // allow access to the document object
        // of the IFrame if we access it through
        // the document.frames array
        IFrameObj = document.frames['RSIFrame'];
```